# Is it better to use a lambda if a variable is not always needed?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-management, lambda, android-viewmodel

I have a class that loads no matter what but only needs a parameter if clicked. Is it better to always pass in the parameter to the class or pass a lambda and invoke that when clicked?

example:

```
class ItemViewModel(item: ProductItem,
                    private val index: Int,
                    private val title: String?){
    fun onItemClick() = foo(title)
}
```

or

```
class ItemViewModel(item: ProductItem,
                    private val index: Int,
                    private val getTitle: () -> String?){
    fun onItemClick() = foo(getTitle)

}
```

Comment: I'm honestly confused :) Show the code you're talking about, don't be shy. Also, passing "a variable" is not usually something to be worried about (assuming you don't intend on creating a 4GB String...).

Comment: added an example. It isn't a very pressing problem, and as I write this I think the answer is going to be just pass the variable because its more readable.

Comment: I would prefer the lamba method, but for the most part it shouldn't matter, more of a case by case basis on this.

Comment: It seems that you are worried about premature optimizations. IMHO, you should always strive to write a simple and clean code, then worry(in most cases you don't) about any optimizations. Passing the first two parameters via the old fashioned way and then passing the last item as a lambda kind of breaks the 'norm' as one might say. Using a lambda over the classic way, in this case, yields no performance benefits. TBH, the class does not give reader info for what purpose it is requiring 3 parameters. If would worry about separating concerns first i.e worry about making it more cohesive.

Comment: If the variable is not "always" needed, I would give it a default value so I don't 'need' to pass an additional argument even when it's not needed.

Comment: Lambda might actually cost more memory than a String, since in JVM bytecode it's represented by an `Object` anyway.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad, there is no way to tell when initializing if the variable is needed.

Comment: Edit the question and include what exactly is going in your code. It's hard to help without having plenty of info.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, and code sample, are several things in one.

1. Is it better to use a lambda if a variable is not always needed?
   If you're using Kotlin (which you are in your example) then your parameter can be set as optional (which you're doing) by marking it with a `?`.
   This means that the caller of this function can pass `null` as a value, and the function should work as expected.

Now, if you ahead of time know that clients will pass `null` (or some value), and you don't care if they do, and you want to make it easier for clients to call this function and not have to pass a parameter, you can mark your parameter as `? = null`.
For example:

```
class ItemViewModel(item: ProductItem,
                    private val index: Int,
                    private val title: String? = null){
    fun onItemClick() = foo(title)
}
```

Keep in mind though that your function `foo` must also accept a possible `null` value for this example.

Or:

```
class ItemViewModel(item: ProductItem,
                    private val index: Int,
                    private val title: String? = "Default title"){
    fun onItemClick() = foo(title)
}
```

This means that you can now call this as `ItemViewModel(ProductionItem.SomeItem, 1)`. A third parameter is not needed (but it is still accepted if you do pass one).

2. Lambda parameters are often only used to say that the parameter you're requiring should be a callback. In other words, you would pass a lambda for something like "onComplete", and let the client handle the response of your `foo` function.
3. Conventionally, you wouldn't pass a parameter (that is not a callback) as a lambda. Sure, you CAN do it, but it's a very strange way of doing it and nobody would understand why you did it.
4. As mentioned in a comment, lambdas are often much more memory consuming than variables (unless your variable is a serialized object, like an image or something like that)

Comment: default value or null would not work in this situation because at any time, a user may click the item. I cannot know when initializing if a user is going to click or not. The best practice seems to be always pass the string for clarity and to prevent a larger object being created unnecessarily.

Comment: sorry, I was trying to explain how to set a default value, since that was one of the things the OP was asking about. the actual use case might've been a wrong exampe.